# Exception while executing batch update/insert on Hibernate/Oracle

Tags: java, spring-data-jpa

I am getting an exception while saving persisting the object into database bellow is code base model:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "customer_data")
public class BsslpCustomerInfo {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "id", length = 10)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "service_Id", length = 50, unique = true, nullable = false)
    private String serviceId;

    @Column(name = "quarter", length = 255, nullable = false)
    private String quarter;

    @Column(name = "year")
    private int year;

    @Column(name = "activated_Customer_Name")
    private String activatedCustomerName;

    @Column(name = "deactivated_Customer_Name")
    private String deactivatedCustomerName;

    @Column(name = "quarter_Start_Date")
    private String quarterStartDate;

    @Column(name = "quarter_End_Date")
    private String quarterEndDate;

    public String getServiceId() {
        return serviceId;
    }

    public void setServiceId(String serviceId) {
        this.serviceId = serviceId;
    }

    public String getQuarter() {
        return quarter;
    }

    public void setQuarter(String quarter) {
        this.quarter = quarter;
    }

    public int getYear() {
        return year;
    }

    public void setYear(int year) {
        this.year = year;
    }

    public String getActivatedCustomerName() {
        return activatedCustomerName;
    }

    public void setActivatedCustomerName(String activatedCustomerName) {
        this.activatedCustomerName = activatedCustomerName;
    }

    public String getDeactivatedCustomerName() {
        return deactivatedCustomerName;
    }

    public void setDeactivatedCustomerName(String deactivatedCustomerName) {
        this.deactivatedCustomerName = deactivatedCustomerName;
    }

    public String getQuarterStartDate() {
        return quarterStartDate;
    }

    public void setQuarterStartDate(String quarterStartDate) {
        this.quarterStartDate = quarterStartDate;
    }

    public String getQuarterEndDate() {
        return quarterEndDate;
    }

    public void setQuarterEndDate(String quarterEndDate) {
        this.quarterEndDate = quarterEndDate;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
}
```

...and this is the "Controller" code :

```
for (BsslpParty bsslp : data) {
    Date activationDate = sdf.parse(bsslp.getAssocStartDate());
    Date deactivationDate = sdf.parse(bsslp.getAssocEndDate());
    if(activationDate.compareTo(startDate)>=0 && activationDate.compareTo(endDate)<=0){
        activeCount++;
        BsslpCustomerInfo bsslpCustomerInfo = new BsslpCustomerInfo();
        bsslpCustomerInfo.setServiceId(bsslp.getBsslpName());
        bsslpCustomerInfo.setActivatedCustomerName(bsslp.getEntitledPartyName());
        bsslpCustomerInfo.setQuarter(quarterDateRange.getStartdate());
        bsslpCustomerInfo.setYear(quarterDateRange.getFinYear());
        bsslpCustomerInfo.setQuarterStartDate(quarterDateRange.getStartdate());
        bsslpCustomerInfo.setQuarterEndDate(quarterDateRange.getEndDate());
        listOfActDeActCust.add(bsslpCustomerInfo);              
    }

    usageMetricschartService.saveAllCustomerData(listOfActDeActCust);
}
```

"Service" implementation:

```
@Override
@Transactional
public void saveAllCustomerData(List<BsslpCustomerInfo> customersData) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    for (BsslpCustomerInfo bsslpCustomerInfo : customersData) {
        usageMetricsCustomersRepository.save(bsslpCustomerInfo);
    }

}
```

It is throwing an error like:

> java.sql.BatchUpdateException: ORA-01722: invalid number
>
> oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwBatchUpdateException(DatabaseError.java:343)
>       org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: could not execute batch; SQL [insert into customer_data
>   (activated_Customer_Name, deactivated_Customer_Name, quarter,
>   quarter_End_Date, quarter_Start_Date, service_Id, year, id) values (?,
>   ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)]; nested exception is
>   org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute batch

I've tried in all the possible ways couldn't figure this out; can anyone please help me on this?

Answer (score 1):

You have defined your *id* to be auto-generated, but for every entity you create, you pass a 0 value to the database. This is because your are using the primitive `int`type which is per default initialized to 0. If you set a value to the *id* field, there is no autogeneration.

Change you *id* property to type `Integer` so that on persisting a *null* value is sent to JPA which will cause the id to be generated.